# How to setAlwaysOnTop() when clicking on a JButton in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I would like to use `setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)` in java.

I want to `setAlwaysOnTop()` when I click on a `JButton` and this JButton has its own `actionListener`

My Problem is I don't know how to set the `JFrame` on top at this situation, because it's not inside the constructor nor there is a method `getFrame()`

I tried creating a method inside the constructor but it does not work :S.

UPDATE:

```
private class optionAction implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == onTop)  //onTop is a menuItem when I click it it should make the frame Always on top.
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true); //This does not work of course just to demonstrat you what I want to do
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code? Where and how did you define the `ActionListener`? In order to get good response always give a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: Are you looking for the root pane's [`setDefaultButton()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html)?

Comment: @Howard Mine is totally wrong. I just got the idea from @Jorgen.ringen  but thats when you `implements` the `ActionListener` to the whole class. I want I want how to do it if I have an `ActionListener` only for the `JButton` how can I pass the JFrame?

Comment: @iMohammad. You've been asked to provide an SSCCE. Without code, it's hard to understand why you can't do what is trivial to do for us. If you want help, provide code.

Comment: okay guys let me provide my current code.

Comment: I've added an `ActionListener` method please check it guys.

Comment: @iMohammad Please provide a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html). From what you have shown us it is not possible to deduce anything (besides that you are talking about button in your question and menu item in your code which does not fit).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct working code for this question is below:

```
private class optionAction implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource() == onTop)  //onTop is a menuItem
            setAlwaysOnTop(true); //This does not work of course just to demonstrate you what I want to do
        }
    }
```

The reason this is does not work because I was setting the `setAlwaysOnTop` on a `JFrame` object, which it doesn't exists in that class.

To set the `setALwaysOnTop` on a `JFrame` you have to remove the `frame.` and just add `setAlwaysOnTop()

Answer (score 1):

An idea might be to pass a reference to your JFrame to the constructor of your implementation of the ActionListener.

Maybe something like this:

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame jFrame;

    public MyActionListener(JFrame jFrame) { 
         this.jFrame = jframe; 
    }

    public void onClick(Event event) {
        jFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about if I have an actionListener for that button only. Not `implemented` in the whole class?

Comment: You mean mean an actionlistener implemented as an anonymous class? That's no problem as long as you have a reference to the JFrame in the same scope as you implement the anonymous actionlistener. Please paste a copy of your code so I can see exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The following code lines show you how it can be done with a direct implementation of `ActionListener()` assigned to a button declared inside the constructor. (You can also do this anywhere else in your class.)

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        // ...

        JButton button = new JButton("PRESS");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                // Alternatively use MyFrame.this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            }
        });
        add(button);

        // ...
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a boolean called ontop

```
boolean ontop = false; 
jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()) {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if (ontop) {
           frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
           ontop = false;
       }
       else {frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true); ontop = true}

});
```